# How is the US-China trade war viewed in Australia?

Tags: united-states, economy, china, australia, public-opinion

A pretty good [question on econ.SE](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/30755/why-is-the-australian-dollar-often-viewed-by-traders-as-a-proxy-for-the-chinese) has highlighted the close relationship between the Australian and Chinese economies.

So, I wonder, how is the US-China trade war viewed in Australia, at a political level? I see that at the recent G20 meeting, Australia's Treasurer [did join](https://www.sbs.com.au/news/collateral-damage-australia-joins-g20-warning-over-us-china-trade-dispute) a declaration deploring the trade war. Do all Australian political parties deplore it, for instance? Or is there a [broader] range of opinions?

Comment: The most likely party to support this trade war is One Nation. Labor and the Greens are too left-wing to endorse something by Trump, and the Nationals will probably have the same opinion as the Liberal Party.

Answer (score 1):

I think, they wouldn't want to discuss this issue again and again. They just made a statement as they had to.

Australia is a close ally of the US and its exports are predominantly to China. Australia's economy grew at a good rate. Many consider the australia is about to face a housing crisis (Like US?). Majority of Australia's Ore exports are to China (~36% ?). At this point, discussing sides on US-China trade considerations will be devastating to AU. The best they can do is to avoid this as much as they can.

Source: https://oec.world/en/profile/country/aus/

Once the US-China trade issues are settled, everything would be back to normal. So, the game is to wait and watch.

Comment: Welcome to Politics! Please try to add references to support your answer. You seem to refer to some statistics, please try to link to their sources.